# How to sync my bookmarks with Chromium from a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb, sync, chromium, bookmarks

Just downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and I have all my Chrome bookmarks saved on my USB flash drive. How do I sync them with Chromium?

Answer (score 1):

If you exported them as an HTML file from Chrome, you can import the file in Chromium by pressing **Shift + Ctrl + O**, then under "Organize", click on "Import bookmarks from HTML file".